# Git - How to change the starting point of a git branch with existing PR?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, rebase, branching-and-merging

I was working on a feature branch for quite some time. Now, I created a pull request to merge my branch but because my branch is very old, so there are many tests that are failing.

I want to **move the starting point of my branch to a new commit** without causing any changes to my existing PR.

I tried this but its not what I want->
I created a new branch and cherry-picked my commits to it. It works but doing this, I will have to create a new PR & there is already some comments on my PR. So, I dont want to lose them.

What I have is something like this:

```
master
A--B--C--D--...--M--...--Y--Z--
       \                   /
        \                 /
feature  nA--nB--nC--nD--nE
```

What I want to do:

```
master
A--B-...--M--..............--Y--Z--
           \                   /
            \                 /
feature      nA--nB--nC--nD--nE
```

Basically move the starting point of feature branch from C to M.

I heard about rebase but I didnt quite understand how that works, is ituseful in this case?
I am a beginner, so please explain/give commands in detail.

Answer (score 2):

> I created a new branch and cherry-picked my commits to it. It works but doing this, I will have to create a new PR

Actually no: you can reset your PR branch to that new branch and force push it.
It should [update the existing PR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32346710/6309), while keeping the comments (which could refer to old obsolete files)

```
git switch -C pr_branch new_branch
git push -f origin pr_branch
```

A `git rebase` could also help in that it would replay your `pr_branch` commits on top of an updated remote branch, but, if you already did manually the work of cherry-picking the relevant commits in your new branch, that should be enough: reset your PR branch to it and force push.

You could experiment on a new PR branch done from an old commit, with a comment: try and force push there to check if this works as advertise.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question.

We suppose to have the following commit hashes:

- M => A0000000
- nA => B000000

The instructions you should issue are:

1. git checkout A000000 -B my-fixed-feature
2. git rebase B000000
3. git branch -D feature

In other words:

1. Create a new branch starting at commit M.
2. Move (rebase) the branch starting at nA after M inside the new branch "my-fixed-feature".
3. Remove the old "feature" branch.

Obviously the step 2 may generates conflicts you should solve.

Unfortunately I did not try that solution, but I applied it several times during my working experience. I hope it may help you.